# What is the best way to update row using spring data with best performance value?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am using spring data. Now I have a task to update entity in very performance and data consistency critical part of the application. There is isLocked field in the entity. Many transactions and business logic relay on this field. I want to be able update this field in the most effective and secure way.

I see two ways:

1. Using `@Query` and jpql update statement. This approach has benefit in doing only one request to db. But i am not sure about transaction safety.
2. Using `findById` with `@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)` and modifying field in java. Cons of this approach is at least 2 requests to db, but transnational safety thanks to lock.

What would you recommend? Maybe there is different most appropriate approach i don't know.

Comment: Are you just using normal transactions? `@Transactional` is nearly always sufficient (though if you don't already have the object on hand for some surprising reason, then executing an update directly removes the need to fetch it first).

Comment: I use `@Transactional`. I am wonder why there are so many examples with updating on java side. Using `@Query` for update more effective, isn't it?

Comment: It's more *efficient*, but you have to write the queries and explicitly execute them, whereas the point of JPA is that you can write normal Java code with POJOs and not worry about database specifics.

Comment: So jpql database agnostic as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking about effectiveness, both options are perfectly effective.  So your choice comes down to non-functional requirements.

You mention **performance** in your question;  the option of using Query will certainly be more performant.  Not only because it will end up doing one database call instead of two (and if you play it smart and you have multiple to update, you might even get away with one call for a whole bunch of records), but also because retrieving an entity to modify it involves hydrating it and adding it to the entity manager session, which is quite expensive compared to a simple Query.  That said and as a general principle, you should only make your decision based on performance when performance becomes an issue (google 'premature optimization' for more on that).

The other aspect to think about is **robustness**.  Typically an entity is more than just a dumb data store.  It contains logic and business rules, and there will certainly be validations there that exist in your codebase, but not in your db.  Using Query circumvents all of that and forces you to encode these business rules in two spots; once in your domain, and once in your queries.  Even if right now the field you're updating is 'dumb', it's not a bad gamble to assume that will not stay like that.

Third is **maintainability**.  The whole idea, the reason that something like JPA exists, is because 'get item from the repository, change the field, and save changes (or commit transaction)' is such a simple thing to write.  There's less chance for errors and anyone can read and reason about it.  If you're not going to use it, why use JPA in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Jpa can handle versioned entities. The current thread can update the entity only if the version property is the same in the object and in the DB.

Simply add the following property to your entity and Spring Data Jpa do the rest:

```
 @Version
 private Long version;
```

When you call the `repository.save(entity)` method, it extends the `UPDATE` query with the following clause: `... and version=?`.
And it also automatically increases the version before save.

Comment: But i less effective than using @Query("Update entity where id =?1")

Comment: The query will be: `Update entity set version=25 where id=1 and version = 24`. You got an exception if the update was unsuccessful. And it doesn't need locking.

Comment: But before that i have to read entity. It's +1 request to db.

Comment: Well, if you want to update the entity you need to know something about it anyway. If you want increase or decrease a property you need the original value. If you simply want to override a property regardless of the previous value then you don't need locking anyway. Maybe you should share the actual usecase.